# Validate the api with user defined roles in spring boot oauth resource server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on resource server implemented by the spring boot o auth 2.0. Spring boot version would be 3.0.0. Need to authrorize the api with user-authorities. I tried below samples.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html. But did n't get the user-authorities attribute. Can anyone sugget me the approach to to validate api with user roles in **@PreAuthorize** anotations.

Sample token format :

{
"sub": "admin@support.com",
"aud": "client",
"user-authorities": [
"READ_PRIVILEGE",
"WRITE_PRIVILEGE"
],
"azp": "client",
"iss": "http://localhost:8080",
"exp": 1676210945,
"iat": 1676209145
}

Answer (score 0):

Two options to override default authorities mapping in case of token introspection (read `user-authorities` claim in your case instead of `scope`).

- override the all `OpaqueTokenIntrospector`, [as explained in the doc you linked](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-authorization-extraction)
- override just the `OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter` to which the default introspector delegates the conversion from **successful** introspection result to an `Authentication` instance

The second option is less intrusive as you don't take responsibility of how introspection is made (which REST client is used, how client authentication is performed, query built, response parsed, exceptions handled, etc.).

Sample usage:

```java
@Bean
OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter introspectionAuthenticationConverter() {
    return (String introspectedToken, OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal authenticatedPrincipal) -> {
        // double check the claim name to extract authorities from and if a prefix should be added:
        // in the sample provided in your question, it is "user-authorities" claim
        // but in the sample linked in your comment, it is "scope" claim and "SCOPE_" prefix should be added for "hasAuthority("SCOPE_openid")" to be matched
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final var rolesClaim = Optional.ofNullable((List<String>) authenticatedPrincipal.getAttribute("user-authorities")).orElse(List.of());
        
        return new BearerTokenAuthentication(
                authenticatedPrincipal,
                new OAuth2AccessToken(
                        TokenType.BEARER,
                        introspectedToken,
                        authenticatedPrincipal.getAttribute(IdTokenClaimNames.IAT),
                        authenticatedPrincipal.getAttribute(IdTokenClaimNames.EXP)),
                // You should insert a ".map()" step to insert a prefix if access-control rules expect one (that is not visible in the access token)
                rolesClaim.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).toList());
    };
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter introspectionAuthenticationConverter)
        throws Exception {

    http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken().authenticationConverter(introspectionAuthenticationConverter);

   ... 

    return http.build();
}
```

Complete sample [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_introspection) with one of "my" starters which make things much simpler (check security conf and properties file against what you have in yours).

Comment: Getting below exception after adding introspectionAuthenticationConverter. AS it was unable to read the parameter. Cannot invoke "java.util.List.stream()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal.getAttribute(String)" is null

updated config files in below repo.

https://github.com/pallintipremkumar/configfiles

Comment: the sample access token you put in your question has user roles in `user-authorities` claim but the conf you reference in your comment uses `scope` claim. I edited my answer to put some null safety, but double check what claim(s) you want to be picked as authorities source.

Comment: Also, the resource-server configuration you link seems incomplete enough (no CORS, session-management nor CSRF configuration for instance), for me thinking you should really spend time reading the tutorial I linked already: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_introspection

Comment: Thank you @ch4mp

It will be more helpful if you can provide me the sample Oauth 2.0 server config with user defined roles enabled with opeaque token.

Comment: This is an other question (this one is about resource-server config). Ask it in another thread.